# Typescript a function returns union type isn't compatible with union of functions

Tags: typescript

Sorry maybe my question title isn't accurate, and I know a function return union is not equivalent to union of functions.

But my case is simple enough and I think it should be correct.

```js
type Functions = (() => 'a') | (() => 'b')

type Returns = 'a' | 'b'

const buildFunction = (returnValue: Returns): Functions => () => returnValue
```

Because the input is one of `'a' | 'b'`, so the built function should also be one of `(() => 'a') | (() => 'b')`.

However there is an error:

```
Type '() => Returns' is not assignable to type 'Functions'.
  Type '() => Returns' is not assignable to type '() => "a"'.
    Type 'Returns' is not assignable to type '"a"'.
      Type '"b"' is not assignable to type '"a"'.
```

---

**Update:**

Thanks @jsejcksn, your solution is great for the above scenario. But my actual scenario is more complex than it, and this solution doesn't seem to solve my problem. Here is what I am facing on:

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiCiA3CA7YUC8UDeVSQC4oByAQ2KgF8oAfHPcCI4gIwsoFgAob-aAdQCWwABYAVAPYApAM4SUAHjEA+TFDFQIAD2CoAJjKgBXFAGsUEgO4puUKAH51UAGT1g0gMoB5AHJEAFACUmKoanFx2RCgQyABO3NwAxvIy6KR6epKy8mr+MajARHBIBYFEQqJZcorFyGiqGKr+2LZQAHQd+WgANK3uUt5+UEEhmnXA3JSBCVzJKKlQ6ZnS1QDiqBCxgokAjGpKJWiaOvqGtQXKeeNEYofAZVAV4ivyCuf1o82tHW1dwL0RPCeXwBYKNMYFSbTHizFJpDJVeTraJbRIAJn2t3Gx10KAMsAQ40ufxudweT0RiixF0+LUBPz+ALs-UGoNGfyhQA)

```
type MyEvent = { type: 'a' } | { type: 'b' }

type WithToJson<T> = T extends unknown
  ? T & { toJSON: () => T }
  : never
// will be { type: 'a'; toJSON: () => { type: 'a' } } | { type: 'b'; toJSON: () => { type: 'b' } }

// adding a `toJSON` method to each event
const addToJson = (event: MyEvent): WithToJson<MyEvent> => ({
  ...event,
  toJSON: () => event  // error
})

// try to use generic function to restrict type, but doesn't work
const addToJsonGeneric1 = <TEvent extends MyEvent>(event: TEvent): WithToJson<MyEvent> => ({
  ...event,
  toJSON: () => event
})

// give the generic type to WithToJson type
const addToJsonGeneric2 = <TEvent extends MyEvent>(event: TEvent): WithToJson<TEvent> => ({
  ...event,
  toJSON: () => event
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Update in response to your comment and updated question:

I now think that this is what you're looking for: a function for assigning a [JSON transformer function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#tojson_behavior) to an object:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAUgzgewHZQLxQEYIQGwgQxQB8okBXHHKE8gWwwgCdqo5hGBLJAcxfmQDaAXRYBvKAIDWEEAC5W7LtyHz+KAL4BuALAAoUJCgBlJh3w4OALyYAeACoAaY6fNX8GPFAgAPYBCQAJnCwiCjoagB8aFAAFABu5mQQ8nYAlGhRJpyulu54Ovrg0AAKjAgBZADGtnZR6DHpqFF2BQbQdggwRgDyAHIAshDAABbl9nVQ4sCdPb3ypeVVNVFaem1QAOocIwDCZGwItF199l6+-kFQCBgAVhCVwE5ZZha5HtA+foHBkdF2UAAyKAdY4DIajAI2Z45PIQCIFPR6ABmZCQDw4yCgtHw0mhr1hUFOnwuwWudweERiCBSqXk+DgcCYwFJUA4wX+QJBs0GIzGtQKKLRwAxKGxuJc+PehL0UGBZy+lzJ90eMuc2UlnmJ3xCyAcekp1OBTkZ6qsTHkeLNjHsTwlbneEVpUDiCA4AQFqPRmLFEEtb08NlV-y1ituyr1ullfoJIZ+oQjBpSxrt1kYAH4LSmarbTf64U6XW7JqrumGHgA6AIQJFcCALSCMUBUpwAcmmoJbTlEqtllWQNe4ZEYsPk7CSEdlsv8ZFoTBHUCR5kZE8nAHdOMB52OICvZQkcEl5CaXlaoGnYo0oseckwqel5A0MlcV+pUgV1IjdHoAPTfqAAVTgfBuA+bx8FoMA8FkT8+yQNgvDiABBaIpiKeQW3wFsoHpKBYPg1Yv10H1o3eGIICQpxyKfGJRDaeRyPLNonFnBlgOSKAWzsYY2SgVccOvV4IACABCFtXzfPRyMQxiZj6BpNCgb8ACooEAXg3AFkdnsoAAP10vS9HrJkQA49tZiwgIEAgYIkAQYAzjZOzMXWFtUMgeQACJ8HchT1BbcsYgAJgAZiCgBOdIlO-GDkEQPByxwBBuBiUtyWActpBAOAyKQ1I30Uv8BHctp3KEPQ8NwCB4sSmJQXLNhOB4DgkRAbLENyhTf0mIqinc2RPPchx3JYoCQN69yuJ4vjggEs0RPcj9COIlNYVaiTdCkmTQXk-KrkkNTNMI8q4oSpKUuVdKZCyqT2p2writK3Qjsqk6atmOrFEa5rVryzrRG6yAxq8hagA)

```ts
type Json = boolean | null | number | string | Json[] | { [key: string]: Json };
type Serializer<T, Serializable extends Json = Json> = (value: T) => Serializable;
type Producer<T> = () => T;
type ToJSONMethod<T> = { toJSON: Producer<T> };
type WithCustomJSON<T extends object, Serializable extends Json> = T & ToJSONMethod<Serializable>;


function makeSerializable <T extends object>(o: T): asserts o is T & ToJSONMethod<T>;
function makeSerializable <
  T extends object,
  Serializable extends Json,
>(o: T, serializer: Serializer<T, Serializable>): void;
function makeSerializable <
  T extends object,
  Serializable extends Json,
>(o: T, serializer?: Serializer<T, Serializable>): void {
  Object.defineProperty(o, 'toJSON', {
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: false,
    writable: true,
    value: serializer ? () => serializer(o) : () => o,
  });
}


// Usage example:

const evA = { type: 'a' as const };

makeSerializable(evA, ev => ({type: ev.type, message: 'This was serialized!'}));
evA.toJSON(); /* 
    ~~~~~~
Property 'toJSON' does not exist on type '{ type: "a"; }'.(2339) */

console.log(Object.keys(evA)); // ["type"]
console.log(JSON.stringify(evA)); // {"type":"a","message":"This was serialized!"}

makeSerializable(evA);
evA.toJSON(); // ok 

console.log(Object.keys(evA)); // ["type"]
console.log(JSON.stringify(evA)); // {"type":"a"}
```

---

Original answer:

If you are trying to restrict the types of arguments that can be provided to the function creator, then you can do it using a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) like this:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAShwFcBOA7AagQwDYOgXigHINCoAfIgI0IG4BYAKEYGMB7FAZ2CkoQEssAEwBiCFM2B92UAgB4YUCAA9gEFII6x4ydNlwA+ABQA3PRABcsAJQz9UQ1csK8d0zgj0mDNp24AzFABBGR5+IVFxSXZDYkIrGigAekT7GxcoACIMDJZ2LigAgCEQ3gERMQkpFBjqeKSUh1tMyhzvPO4MEIDAhwTkzOzc3x4ulELe+ubWofyAgGESsPLIqpjmOL6AKkYoXb39g8ODgD9TxkCkAHMEAFs1blY-KFBIIgzmDNI+TRRWDo4OHxLigMJQsNBgKwoGAMEgMHdVEgoI9nuBoIQ4IhUJh3IQAHSGABMAGYACwAVhsm0SjCAA)

```ts
type ReturnValue = 'a' | 'b';

const buildFunction = <R extends ReturnValue>(value: R) => (): R => value;

const fnA = buildFunction('a'); // () => "a"
const fnB = buildFunction('b'); // () => "b"
const a = fnA(); // "a"
const b = fnB(); // "b"

const fnC = buildFunction('c'); /*
                          ~~~
Argument of type '"c"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReturnValue'.(2345) */
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your solution is great for this scenario. But I am so sorry because I don't describe my actual scenario in the question, so your solution can't solve my real problem. 

I will update my question with my real use case, and please feel free to have a look. Thanks.

Comment: @Suerta I looked, but I don't see an update to your question.

Comment: I have updated it. Thanks.

Comment: @Suerta See my updated answer